# How to perform a simple seque using the tap of a button

Tags: xcode, swift2, segue

I want to flip a modal view by using a segue in Swift. How can I do this?

I have this base view:

[image: Image of base view]

From the left button "Setup", I want to call another view via a segue (Flip horizontal).

[image: Zoom in of final product]

Answer (score 0):

No need to write a single line of code, simply control-drag to the destination view controller from the button.

Comment: ok, i did this from the button to the navigation controller where the view is embed and nothing happens... I also drag to the view itself